# Python console call HCMGIS "Centerline in polygons' gaps"

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-python-console

I use QGIS 3.10 (Python 3.7 via the console) and want to automate a few processes through a Python script (I'm a beginner in programming with Python). I have a layer with many polygons ('polygons') and want to create the centerline between them. When I do this step without a script I use the HCMGIS plugin --> "Geometry Processing" --> "Centerline in polygons' gaps". How can I call this function in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HCMGIS ver 20.4.20 (approved soon), try this in QGIS Console:

```
from HCMGIS.hcmgis_library import *
input = "D:\\osm\\block.shp" # your polygon input
output = "D:\\osm\\centerline.shp" #  your centerline output in .sqlite, .shp, .geojson, .gpkg,  or kml
hcmgis_centerline(input, 1, True, 2,output,status_callback = None)
##hcmgis_centerline(layer,density,chksurround,distance,output,status_callback = None):
##density (float value): densify geometries with given an interval (in this case the density is 1 meter). Smaller density value returns smoother centerline but slower
##chksurround: if chksurround is True, then the function will also create a surrounding 'centerline' with a "distance" to the bounding box of building block
```

You can also call other functions of HCMGIS Plugin Library in QGIS Python Console or even in stand alone PyQGIS application in  [HCMGIS Plugin Library Call](https://github.com/thangqd/HCMGIS/blob/master/callhcmgis.py)

[image: Call QGIS Plugin Library in QGIS Pythong Console]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will wait for the HCMGIS ver 20.4.20.
In ver 20.4.12 I get the message that the parametervalue of "input" is wrong..

Comment: Done! http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/stable/?page=42&sort=downloads&

Comment: Many thanks for the super fast support! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to upload new version of HCMGIS Plugin and I will show u how to call HCMGIS function in QGIS Python console or PyQGIS as soon as it's approved on HCMGIS Plugin repo.